# What is the possible reason and fix for this exception regarding bitronix configuration in MOQUI

Tags: moqui, bitronix

When I start the server I get an exception like :

```
bitronix.tm.Configuration 
cannot get this JVM unique ID. Make sure it is configured and you only use ASCII characters. Will use IP address instead (unsafe for production usage!)
```

What is the reason for this kind of exception and how can I fix this, when loading my component to production instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of Bitronix configuration, the "bitronix.tm.serverId" property in the bitronix-default-config.properties file. See the docs for more details here:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/Configuration2x